# How do you develop an app using wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

Build an App that uses wx.TextCtrl to input USGS gagin stations and usewx.adv.DatePickerCtrl to choose the beginning and ending date, download the daily data from USGS based on the input stations and dates; and show the data from USGS based on the input stations and dates; and show the data in a Grid control. Use wx.FileDialog to save the data as a CSV file

Comment: This question is too general, please ask more specific question.

Comment: I need help getting started on the basic code foundation, I have never used WXpython before and am at a loss on how to accomplish this

Comment: @DanielJoseph A good place to start would be the documentation [here](https://docs.wxpython.org/). wxPython also has really helpful demos and samples, which you can find by heading to [here](https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/), clicking on the link matching your wxPython version and clicking the wxPython-demo tar.gz file (to download it).